# Does Azure SQL Database support two-phase commit (2PC)?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, azure, azure-sql-database, distributed-transactions

Because I have several unrelated resources to coordinate during commit, I would like to use two-phase commit (2PC) on Azure SQL Database, from Java code (JDBC).

On standard SQL Server, you can do a [complex install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335.aspx) of some DLL plus some scripts to make available some extended stored procedures, with names like `xp_sqljdbc_xa_init` or `xp_sqljdbc_xa_prepare`, that in turn the Microsoft JDBC driver uses to provide the XA semantics of start/end/prepare/commit. But these extended stored procedures aren't available on Azure from what I can see.

Also, by itself, SQL Server doesn't seem to have any `PREPARE TRANSACTION` primitive, and I don't find one in Azure either.

So how can one do 2PC on Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported and in many ways incompatible with the benefits and uses cases for cloud computing. There's an [excellent blog post by Clemens Vasters](http://vasters.com/clemensv/2012/07/30/Transactions+In+Windows+Azure+With+Service+Bus+Ndash+An+Email+Discussion.aspx) that I'd recommend reading and which introduces the service bus feature as a way to accommodate the key aspects of the behavior that you may be looking for.

Comment: Thanks. SQL Server is nevertheless the only SQL database I know of that doesn't have a `PREPARE` statement.